# Codeigniter submit form not working, blank page

Tags: codeigniter

I'm attempting to submit a form with codeigniter and when i submit the form a get a blank page.  Where did i go wrong?

View

```
echo "<form class='order_ctn_parent' method='POST' action='add/insert_orders'>";
//inputs
echo "</form>";
```

Controller

```
class Add extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {

    }


       public function insert_orders()
    {
        $this->load->model('order_model', 'order');

        $this->order->insert_orders();
        redirect('view_orders', 'location');
    }

}
```

Model

```
class Order_model extends CI_Model {    
public function insert_orders()
        {
        $DB2 = $this->load->database('orders', TRUE);

                $timber_array = $this->input->post("timber_choose");
                $products_array = $this->input->post("product_choose");
                $qty_array = $this->input->post("quantity");
                $price_array = $this->input->post("price");
                $qty_array = $this->input->post("quantity");


                $loop = 0;
                foreach($products_array as $product) {

                    $price = str_replace("£","",$price_array[$loop]);

                    $data = array(
                       'product_code' => "",
                       'timber_type' => $timber_array[$loop],
                       'product' => $product,
                       'quantity' => $qty_array[$loop],
                       'price' =>  $price
                    );

                    $DB2->insert('timber_order_products', $data); 

                    $loop++;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: These user guide links will help with form submitting http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
?>//end of php

<form class='order_ctn_parent' method='POST' action='<?php echo base_url()?>add/insert_orders'>

</form>
```

and load model in `__construct()`, like this

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('order_model', 'order');
}
```

and no need of check `$DB2 = $this->load->database('orders', TRUE);`

and Codeigniter insert should be [Like This](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your url after submitting . i am sure your form action is not working . give proper controller and its function url into Form action . example is here .

```
<?php echo site_url('add/insert_orders);?>
```

where add will be your controller and insert_orders will be function of add controller.

Comment: base url best in form action I think

Comment: Yes he can use if he want to use base_url .